# Getter for java array returns null

Tags: java, arrays

When I use a getter to return the value of an array, it declares null. However, this does not occur if I define the array outside the class constructor, unfortunately as it is defined by a for loop it must be in the constructor.
The getter:

```
public static String[] getLetters(){
    return dispLetter;
}
```

The for loop that defines the array:

```
for(int i=0; i<16; i++){
        int letterSelect = (int) (Math.random()*6+1);
        System.out.print(letterSelect+",");
        dispLetter[i]=letters[dice[i]-1][letterSelect-1];
```

The loop were it is refrenced in the other class:

```
for(int i=0; i<16;i++){
        grid[i]=new JLabel(" "+Dice.getLetters()[i]+" ");
        grid[i].setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 68));
        grid[i].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        grid[i].setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    }
```

The entire "Dice" class if needed:

```
package excersize.pkg9;

import java.util.Random;

public class Dice {
    private static String dispLetter[] = new String[16];

    public Dice() {
        int dice[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};

        for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++) {
            dice[i] = i + 1;
        }

        Random rnd = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++) {
            int changeBy = rnd.nextInt(dice.length);
            int value = dice[i];
            dice[i] = dice[changeBy];
            dice[changeBy] = value;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(dice[i] + ",");
        }

        String letters[][] = new String[][]{
                {"A","F","P","K","F","S"},
                {"E","T","T","R","L","Y"},
                {"D","E","Y","L","V","R"},
                {"C","P","O","H","A","S"},
                {"I","Y","S","D","T","T"},
                {"N","E","E","H","G","W"},
                {"R","N","Z","N","L","H"},
                {"R","D","I","X","E","L"},
                {"Qu","N","M","I","H","U"},
                {"T","S","E","I","S","O"},
                {"T","T","O","A","O","W"},
                {"V","T","H","R","W","E"},
                {"S","I","E","N","E","U"},
                {"T","U","I","C","O","M"},
                {"B","O","A","J","O","B"},
                {"G","A","E","A","N","E"},
        };

        System.out.println();

        for(int i=0; i<16; i++){
            int letterSelect = (int) (Math.random()*6+1);
            System.out.print(letterSelect+",");
            dispLetter[i]=letters[dice[i]-1][letterSelect-1];
        }

        System.out.println();

        for(int i=0; i<dispLetter.length; i++){
            System.out.print(dispLetter[i]+",");
        }
    }

    public static String[] getLetters(){
        return dispLetter;
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to show the code that actually invokes the getter.

Comment: `dispLetter` is static.  Its initialization is not.  That's generally a bad sign. It looks like `dispLetter` should not be static in the first place, or the initialization needs to move to a static initializer block.

Comment: you iterate `dice[]` and put 1-16 numbers that already has 1-16 numbers on it. a redunduncy of work occured there.

Comment: i guess you are calling the static getter before you 'new' the class which does initialization. You probably need to resolve your static/dynamic misalignment.

Comment: It isn't 'defined by a loop'. It is *initialized* by a loop. It is defined by its declaration statement, which should be at class level, not inside the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its generally not a good idea to initialize a static member in a constructor.
You are referencing `dispLetter` before it has been initialized in the `Dice()` constructor. Remove the `static` modifier from `dispLetter` and its getter method

Then, the code should work fine after this change :

Replace

```
grid[i]=new JLabel(" "+Dice.getLetters()[i]+" ");
```

with

```
grid[i]=new JLabel(" "+(new Dice().getLetters()[i])+" ");
```

**OR**
If you really think `dispLetter` should remain `static` , then move the code in the constructor to a static initialzer block :

```
static {
int dice[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
    for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++) {
        dice[i] = i + 1;
    }
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++) {
        int changeBy = rnd.nextInt(dice.length);
        int value = dice[i];
        dice[i] = dice[changeBy];
        dice[changeBy] = value;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(dice[i] + ",");
    }

    String letters[][] = new String[][]{
            {"A","F","P","K","F","S"},
            {"E","T","T","R","L","Y"},
            {"D","E","Y","L","V","R"},
            {"C","P","O","H","A","S"},
            {"I","Y","S","D","T","T"},
            {"N","E","E","H","G","W"},
            {"R","N","Z","N","L","H"},
            {"R","D","I","X","E","L"},
            {"Qu","N","M","I","H","U"},
            {"T","S","E","I","S","O"},
            {"T","T","O","A","O","W"},
            {"V","T","H","R","W","E"},
            {"S","I","E","N","E","U"},
            {"T","U","I","C","O","M"},
            {"B","O","A","J","O","B"},
            {"G","A","E","A","N","E"},

    };

    System.out.println();
    for(int i=0; i<16; i++){
        int letterSelect = (int) (Math.random()*6+1);
        System.out.print(letterSelect+",");
        dispLetter[i]=letters[dice[i]-1][letterSelect-1];
    }
    System.out.println();
    for(int i=0; i<dispLetter.length; i++){
        System.out.print(dispLetter[i]+",");
    }
    }

public Dice() {
}
```